# Split output data text file where paragraphs and tables are mixed

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text, split

I have a number of output text files from a software program which mix section titles, description and tables all in the same file. I need to find a way to extract the data reliably. The file looks generally as follows:

```
section title, a=1
description, description, description

x,y,z,p
(m),(m),(m),(psi)
0,0,0
0,0,1
...

section title, a=2
description, description, description

a,k,r
(ft),(mm),(f)
4,4,1
0,0,1

section title, a=3
description, description, description
...
```

So far my approach is to read everything into a string:

```
with open(file) as f:
    raw_data = f.read().strip()
```

then use the `re` library like:

```
re.split(r"section title,\s+a=\d+", raw_data)
```

problem is, then the value of `a` acts as a delimiter and disappears, when I'd actually like to keep it and instead just split before it.

I know I can "keep" it if I group it like `re.split(r"section title,\s+a=\d+", raw_data)`, but then I have a list of mismatched data where every other item is one little number and the table data is all interspersed, which is not ideal, i.e.:

```
['1', '<long string with table>', '2', '<another long string>', '3', ...]
```

ideally, the output would be something where I can get the a value as a key and the table data as its value. I can manage it with the techniques I'm using but it seems like the wrong way to go about it.

I'm not sure what the normal approach to handling something like this would be, so I'm looking for other options and more elegant solutions.

Comment: How about not including the number in the split `section title,\s+a=` ?

Comment: Another approach is to not use split, just a normal find type thing `section title, a=(\d+)\s*((?:(?!section title, a=)[\S\s])*?)\s*`

Comment: @sln: that first suggestions is true thanks. However, assuming I need to keep the whole title and the info it contains, how would I go around that is kind of what I'm hoping to figure out

Comment: @sln the `?!` may be that answer I was looking for; I've never used a negative look-ahead match; looks very interesting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That stops the match, dividing the string into section titles

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the number when splitting, you just need to use a capturing group.

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

See [`re.split`'s docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

Using your initial approach and `re.split`, you'd get:

```
['', '1', '\ndescription, description, description\n\nx,y,z,p\n(m),(m),(m),(psi)\n0,0,0\n0,0,1\n...\n\n', '2', '\ndescription, description, description\n\na,k,r\n(ft),(mm),(f)\n4,4,1\n0,0,1\n\n', '3', '\ndescription, description, description', ... ]
```

With that you could have a function to parse the data as follows:

```
def parse_data(raw_data):
    parts = re.split(r'section title,\s+a=(\d+)', raw_data)
    return {key: table for key, table in zip(parts[1::2], parts[2::2])}
```

which yields the result:

```
{'1': '\ndescription, description, description\n\nx,y,z,p\n(m),(m),(m),(psi)\n0,0,0\n0,0,1\n...\n\n',
 '2': '\ndescription, description, description\n\na,k,r\n(ft),(mm),(f)\n4,4,1\n0,0,1\n\n',
 '3': '\ndescription, description, description'}
```

Note that the appropriate technique for this would depend on the format of the file and any guarantees that you could assume.

ps: I'm not sure whether you want to keep the line `description, description, description` and what about the new lines.